# How can i return different value from what was in the dropdown in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I am working with dropbox, but what i want to do is retrieve value depending on what the user chooses on the dropbox; for example the users picks "apple" on the dropdownbox what i want to return will be "Vitamin C"

Here is what i have so far:

```
String myFruits;

  List<String> fruits = [
    "APPLE",
    "ORANGE",
    "BANANA",];

        DropdownSearch(
          onChanged: (dynamic value) {
            myFruits = value;
          },
          mode: Mode.DIALOG,
          items: fruits,
        ),
```

For now when i print myFruits what it shows is the selected value of the dropbox, what I want is that if pick apple it will return "vitamin c" like that. Thanks :) How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a Map from fruits and returnedValue like:

```
Map<String, String> returnedValue = {
  "APPLE" : "Vitamin A",
  "ORANGE" : "Vitamin C",
  "BANANA" : "Vitamin K",
};
```

and return from this.

---

all your code like this :

```
   Function(String) returnFunction();

   String myFruits;
   String myVitamin;

   List<String> fruits = [
     "APPLE",
     "ORANGE",
     "BANANA",
   ];
   Map<String, String> returnedValue = {
      "APPLE" : "Vitamin A",
      "ORANGE" : "Vitamin C",
      "BANANA" : "Vitamin K",
   };
```

---

```
        DropdownSearch(
          onChanged: (dynamic value) {
            myFruits = value;
            myVitamin = returnedValue[value];
            returenFunction(myVitamin); // if you want return from this class
          },
          mode: Mode.DIALOG,
          items: fruits,
        ),
```

Comment: sorry i am new to dart, can you elaborate morewhat do you mean by returnFunction? I am having trouble implementing it.

Comment: Also you can use 2 lists containing fruits in one and vitamins in another and use index when selecting. i.e vitamins[fruits.indexOf(value)]